# Reference Request( Problems in analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

In about 20 days, I have an examination coming up that has questions in real analysis and algebra. The questions asked are difficult to find anywhere. Although I am reasonably prepared with algebra, analysis is always a struggle for me. Can anyone suggest some uncommon problem list in analysis? Please note that I am familiar with Kaczor and Nowak.

Comment: You could treat Gelbaum & Olmsted, Counterexamples in Analysis, as an uncommon problem list.

Comment: See also "Solving Problems in Mathematical Analysis, Part I: Sets, Functions, Limits, Derivatives, Integrals, Sequences and Series", 
Author: Tomasz Radożycki,
Publisher: Springer,
Year: 2020